# Recover data on BitLocker SED from a non-Windows OS

Tags: windows, sed, bitlocker

I would like to recover the data on a BitLocker locked self-encrypting drive (eDrive compliant) from a non-Windows machine. I have the recovery key that BitLocker let me save, but how do I extract the actual SED password so that I can use a utility like sed-util to recover the data?

Comment: The best method to use is to disable Bitlocker then access the data.  I would not trust ANY Bitlocker implementation other then Bitlocker if I the data was important.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm understanding eDrive management, if Bitlocker recognized the drive as an eDrive, it does nothing else than activate the password protection of the drive. The encryption is internally made in the drive, so when unlocked you should access the data as it wasn't encrypted. If it's not the case, it probably means that there was double encryption:eDrive(hard)+BitLocker(soft)